# Sorting out data by insert and copy and paste special

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to sort out data. 
This is the given data. The list goes on and the numbers of 123 will vary.

```
Header  Header                      
A         1    2    3   4   5       
B         1    2    3   4   5   6   7
C         1    2        
....
....
....
```

What it should look after being sort out

```
Header  Header 
 A      1
 A      2
 A      3
 A      4
 A      5
 B      1
 B      2
 B      3
 B      4
 B      5 
 B      6
 B      7
 C      1
 C      2
```

I have tried doing the codes for this by using insert, copy and paste special. I am trying to work with a small number first to test out but it doesn't seem to work with the loop. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can do this or what can improve on?

```
s = 3
x = 0
w = 2
For d = 0 To 1 Step 1
    y = 3
    x = 0
    Do Until IsEmpty(Sheet1.Cells(w, y).Value)
        y = y + 1
        x = x + 1
    Loop
    Rows(s & ":" & v + 2).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    z = x + 2
    Set ran = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(w, s), Sheet1.Cells(w, z))
    ran.Copy
    Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(s, w), Sheet1.Cells(s, w)).PasteSpecial 
    Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
   False, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ran.Clear
    w = w + v + 1
    s = s + v
Next d
```

Comment: Is using Insert, Copy, and PasteSpecial a requirement, or just the approach that you chose. There are better ways to accomplish the end result.

Comment: @RichHolton it is just the approach i chose. Do you have any other suggestions ? I am open for it

Comment: One method is to use another sheet. Put "A" plus the first number in the first row on the other sheet, then "A" plus the second number on the second row, and so on. Then do the same for all the rows in the first sheet. When that's done, use Range.Sort to sort the second sheet. Finally, copy the data back to the first sheet.

Comment: @RichHolton the method to put is to copy and paste ?

Comment: No. In VBA you can assign the value of one cell directly to another cell. Copy and Paste is pretty inefficient, especially one cell at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took so many time but here we go,

```
Sub mertinc()
    Dim mert, inc As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("a1048576").Select
    mert = Selection.End(xlUp).Row

    Dim mertindex As Integer
    mertindex = 1

    Do While mertindex <= mert
        Range("a" & mertindex).Activate
        inc = Range(Selection.Offset(0, 1), Selection.End(xlToRight)).Count

        Range(Selection.Offset(0, 1), Selection.End(xlToRight)).Copy

        Range("XX1048576").Select
        Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select


        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

        Range("XW1048576").Select
        Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(inc, 1).Select


        Selection.Value = Range("a" & mertindex).Value

        mertindex = mertindex + 1
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```

In this example, you can get exactly what you want in the **XW** and **XX** columns. You can create another page to create this list over there, or you can clear your previous list and copy new one instead of them. That's up to you now.

If you don't understand any part of the code, let me know.

Comment: The XX and XW columns i can change to the column what I want right ?

Comment: And why select 1048576 but not other numbers

Comment: Yes, definitely. 
The only thing you should consider is, each column should have at least 2 cell filled next to it. (If there is anyone with only 1 cell, please add anything next to it. Whether 0 or - or anything.) Otherwise xlToRight can go to somewhere else.
1048576 is the last row of the Excel. That's why I go to that cell then going upward by clicking CTRL + Up arrow.

Comment: I have data with columns of less than 2 cells. i don't think it will work. Izzit possible for it to detect that it is less than 2 and just copy the range and paste?  But still a nice job done

Comment: Now that's fixed. Instead of starting from B column to go to xlRight, now I am starting from A column and then deselecting A by Offset function.

Comment: @Mertinc I posted [an improvement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43842668/3219613) of your code to show you how you can follow the [VBA Best Practices](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices) Guide. If you follow this guide for your future projects it makes you run into less issues during progamming, makes your code run faster and makes it much better readable to other users. I tried not to change your code too much so you can see the differences between good and bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to see how we can improve [Mertinc's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43840259/3219613) to follow best practices with some minor improvements.

*This is expressly not to blame anyone but good for learning purpose and seeing the differences.*

```
Option Explicit

Sub TransformData()
    Dim lastRowScr As Long, lastRowDest As Long
    Dim numCols As Long
    
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")   '* worksheet with source data
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")  '* another worksheet to paste data
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    lastRowScr = wsSrc.Range("A" & wsSrc.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '* determine last row in column A

    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = 1

    Do While iRow <= lastRowScr
        With wsSrc.Range(wsSrc.Range("B" & iRow), wsSrc.Range("A" & iRow).End(xlToRight))
            numCols = .Count
            .Copy
        End With
        
        With wsDest
            lastRowDest = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If IsEmpty(.Range("B" & lastRowDest)) Then lastRowDest = lastRowDest - 1 '* make sure that we start in row 1
            
            .Range("B" & lastRowDest + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
            .Range("A" & lastRowDest + 1).Resize(numCols, 1).Value = wsSrc.Range("A" & iRow).Value
        End With
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

*This procedure uses `sheet1` as data source and inserts the transformed data into `sheet2`.*

---

## Explanations

Here I try to explain the differences and show some further literature.

#### 1. Always use descriptive variable and procedure/function naming

Using your username for naming procedures and variables

```
Sub mertinc()
    Dim mert, inc As Long
```

is bad practice instead you should use descriptive names like

```
Sub TransformData()
    Dim lastRowScr As Long, lastRowDest As Long
    Dim numCols As Long
```

also every variable needs to be specified with a type. `Dim mert, inc As Long` will leave `mert` as variant and only declares `inc` as long.

*Much better readability for yourself and other persons and therefore probably less issues in your codes.*

---

#### 2. Always use long instead of integer

Never use integer unless you need to interop with an old API call that expects a 16 bit int. There is no advantage [using integer instead of long](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613).

---

#### 3. Avoid using Select or Activate

Instead of using `.Select` or `.Activate`

```
Range("a1048576").Select
lastRowScr = Selection.End(xlUp).Row
```

use a direct access

```
lastRowScr = Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row
```

*Much faster and shorter code.*

---

#### 4. Also never assume the worksheet

Always use full qualified ranges

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lastRowScr = ws.Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row
```

*Less issues. If another sheet was selected, this code still works.*

---

#### 5. Never use fixed row counts

Instead of fixed row counts

```
lastRowScr = ws.Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row
```

always detect the last row

```
lastRowScr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

*Different Excel versions have different max. row counts. Therefore this code runs version independent.*

Comment: This is really detailed ! thumbs up for this learned a lot :)

Comment: They are nice and useful suggestions Peh, thanks. Always learning! To be able to answer @RachelChia faster, I just focused on solving the issue asap. But I'll edit my answer soon based on your suggestions.

Comment: @Mertinc If you keep your original code (eg. below your announced edits) then anyone can learn from this. I just posted this for a good practice learning purpose.